# Is it ok to return None from __new__?

Tags: python, new-operator

In general, is it reasonable to return None from a `__new__` method if the user of the class knows that sometimes the constructor will evaluate to None?

The documentation doesn't imply it's illegal,  and I don't see any immediate problems (since `__init__` is not going to be called, None not being an instance of the custom class in question!). But I'm worried about

1. whether it might have other unforeseen issues
2. whether it's a good programming practice to have constructors return None

Specific example:

```
class MyNumber(int):
    def __new__(cls, value): # value is a string (usually) parsed from a file
        if value == 'N.A.':
            return None
        return int.__new__(cls, value)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not illegal.  If nothing weird is done with the result, it will work.

Comment: or rather, it _will_ work. Attempting to do almost anything interesting with the result _will not_. But that's probably part of the point.

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid this.  The documentation doesn't exhaustively list the things you shouldn't do, but it says what `__new__` *should* do: return an instance of the class.

If you don't want to return a new object in some cases, raise an exception.

Comment: But documentation also says that if an instance of the class is not returned, __init__ is not called. I read it as implicitly allowing returning non-instance of the class. As for exceptions, it's a bit more work for the user; instead of just checking that the object is not None, they need to try and catch exceptions.

Comment: Or it's a bit less work for the user, if the user is expecting to handle errors for a block of code with a single exception handler (which is the whole point of exceptions).  Two things to remember: error handling in Python is usually (not *always*, but most of the time) done via exceptions; and having a constructor *not* construct an object is the very definition of *exceptional behavior*.

Comment: In this case, it's not an exceptional situation. The user of the class populates his own data structure with values of MyNumber class, and he's perfectly fine having some None values in there. If he treats this as an exception, he'll just have to populate the with None manually every time it happens. Does this change your view?

Comment: It seems like a strange design, and having a class ctor return None would be very surprising to me.  I'd probably sooner use a factory function; having a factory return None seems much less surprising than a ctor doing so.  Maybe that's just my C++ roots--personally I'd be inclined to avoid it, but it's up to you.  It's unusual, but yes, it's legal.

Comment: My take is that there really isn't _much_ (if any) difference between a class and a factory. A class is a callable so why would it be surprising to have a class return None?

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth: A class is a callable with specific expected behavior: to return an instance of that class.  Having a class ctor return the PID or the amount of free disk space would also be surprising. (Well--may as well preempt this--unless the class is a subclass of `int`.)

Comment: @Glenn Maynard But by the same token a factory is a callable with a specific expected behavior: to return an instance of that class. So why is it any different for the class callable? It seems like another situation of people don't do it so it shouldn't be done. sort of like attributes on functions. It strikes me as a weak reason but meh.