# Not creating an object when conditions are not met in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Is it possible to not create an object if certain conditions are not met in the constructor of a class?

E.g.:

```
class ABC:
    def __init__(self, a):
        if a > 5:
            self.a = a
        else:
            return None

a = ABC(3)
print(a)
```

This should print `None` (since it should not create an Object but return `None` in this case) but currently prints the Object...

Comment: You could raise an exception

Comment: That would be one option but the object will still be created and use memory, right?

Comment: Not by the time you're in `__init__`, that's called after the object is created to initialize the new instance. https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/04/16/python-object-creation-sequence has some details on the sequence - I haven't done this myself enough to have the details at my fingers but maybe a custom `__new__`. It's probably easier to just control your caller, if that's an option for your circumstances.

Comment: `__init__` is not a constructor in Python. Use `__new__` otherwise the object will exist already, you are initializing its values with `__init__`

Comment: `__init__` is *not the constructor*, the object has already been created (what do you think the `self` parameter will get passed?)

Comment: this maybe an helpful answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860469/is-it-ok-to-return-none-from-new

Comment: @progmatico: Thanks for the answer. That is exactly what I wanted. What I amnot able to do, yet, is use the `__new__` to create or not create an object...

Comment: You could just do the sane thing and check this condition outside of `__init__`, and set the object to `None` if the condition is not satisfied.

Comment: If the check is complicated and I want to make it easier for the user it is better placed inside the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this shows the principle. Note that returning `None` is not returning a new object because `None` is a singleton in Python, but of course it is still an object. Note also that `__init__` will not be called as `None` is not an `A` class object.

```
class A():
    def __new__(cls, condition):
        if condition:
            obj = super().__new__(cls)
            return obj

a = A(True)
print(a)
a1 = A(False)
print(a1)
```

This outputs:

```
<__main__.A object at 0x7f64e65c62e8>
None
```

**Edit:**

I tried to directly address your question, by showing the **new** behaviour. But I think all the answers and comments here are good contributions.

So the proper answer is more about how you should do this kind of thing.

I recommend, more or less in this order depending on your taste and context:

1. "do the sane thing" by @Matt Messersmith. Test condition outside the class in client code and create the object only when appropriate.
2. "If the check is complicated and I want to make it easier for the user, it is better placed inside the class." by MrCarnivore. Maybe, maybe not. You can group validation code in functions inside a module that you import and call from the outside, still like in 1) mostly because validation rules can be repetitive or even apply to different kinds of objects. This also hides validation complexity from the client code.
3. raise an exception and use a try block in client code, by @Farhan.K. This is probably the more pythonic way if you test inside the class. You can still invoke an external data validation function inside the class for this.
4. define a classmethod in the class that acts as an alternate constructor by @salparadise. This is a good option.
5. go with a condition inside `__new__` but do not pass it as an arg, or you have to use varargs to deal with that calls and `__init__` calls. Then if you need varargs for other reasons, does not look a good option.

So I end up recommending several answers and options, except my own example. But I was only illustrating the main point of the question anyway.

Comment: What is the `super()`?

Comment: it's calling the constructor of the superclass object, from wich A derives and it's making a new object for you.

Comment: Is there a difference to using `object` instead (like in my own answer)?

Comment: I think there is no difference if the parent class is object, otherwise it will bypass intermediate subclasses directly to object class while searching for a superclass method named `__new__`

Comment: I think also your  answer is ok, but I was writing mine while you were posting yours :)

Comment: I was only able to find my answer with your help!

Comment: So, How would I initiate this object?

Answer (score 5):

you can use a `classmethod` as an alternate constructor and return what you want:

```
class ABC:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    @classmethod
    def with_validation(cls, a):
        if a > 5:
            return cls(a)
        return None


a = ABC.with_validation(10)

a
<__main__.ABC at 0x10ceec288>

a = ABC.with_validation(4)

a

type(a)
NoneType
```

Comment: Also a nice idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This code seems to show that an exception raised in an `__init__()` gives you the effect you want:

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self):
        raise Exception("invalid condition")

class E:
    def __call__(self):
        raise Exception("raise")

def create(aType):
    return aType()

def catchEx():
    e = E()
    funcs=[Obj, int, e]

    for func in funcs:
        try:
            func()
            print('No exception:', func)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

catchEx()
```

Output:

```
invalid condition
No exception: <class 'int'>
raise
```

Comment: Thanks for the example with exceptions!

Answer (score 2):

With the help from @progmatico and a little try and error I managed to come to this solution:

```
class ABC:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) > 0:
            arg = args[0]
        else:
            arg = kwargs['a']

        if arg <= 5:
            return None
        return object.__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.a)

a = ABC(a=3)
print(a)
b = ABC(a=7)
print(b)
```